# Command Faster that `grep ^GE "${TMPFILE2}" | wc -l`

Tags: unix, grep

I am looking for alternate command to

`grep ^GE "${TMPFILE2}" | wc -l`

There are six similar commands in my script that are looking for different patterns and storing the count of result in variables.

Above mentioned command is taking lot of time to search for pattern ^GE in  TMPFILE2 since file size is big

Is there any way to speed up this by using perl or awk.
Or
By any method Can we club these six searches in one and can speed up this?

Comment: What are the other five matches? You could likely write a single awk script to match (and count) them all in a single pass.

Answer (score 2):

**One More Possibility**

Just for completeness, you could try searching in parallel and see how well your OS caches files!

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -c "^ISA" file > isa.tmp &
grep -c "^IEA" file > iea.tmp &
grep -c "^ST"  file > st.tmp  &
grep -c "^SE"  file > se.tmp  &
grep -c "^GS"  file > gs.tmp  &
grep -c "^GE"  file > ge.tmp  &
wait
isa=$(cat isa.tmp)
iea=$(cat iea.tmp)
st=$(cat st.tmp)
se=$(cat se.tmp)
gs=$(cat gs.tmp)
ge=$(cat ge.tmp)
echo $isa $iea $st $se $gs $ge
```

**Revised Answer**

Now that you have given us the search patterns, there may be other options:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -E "^(ISA|IEA|ST|SE|GS|GE)" file > tmp$$
isa_count=$(grep -c "^ISA" tmp$$)
iea_count=$(grep -c "^IEA" tmp$$)
st_count=$(grep -c "^ST" tmp$$)
se_count=$(grep -c "^SE" tmp$$)
se_count=$(grep -c "^GS" tmp$$)
ge_count=$(grep -c "^GE" tmp$$)
echo $isa_count $iea_count $st_count $se_count $ge_count
```

Or this:

```
awk '
    /^ISA/ {isa++;next}
    /^IEA/ {iea++;next}
    /^ST/  {st++;next}
    /^SE/  {se++;next}
    /^GS/  {gs++;next}
    /^GE/  {ge++;next}
    END{ print isa,iea,st,se,gs,ge}' file
```

**Original Answer**

Yes, do them all in one go with `egrep`:

```
egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3..." file
```

like this:

```
egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3..." file > tmp$$
grep -c pattern1 tmp$$
grep -c pattern2 tmp$$
```

Try to keep the search anchored at start of line (with `^`) if possible.

Note, I believe `egrep` is deprecated, and we are supposed to use `grep -E` instead.

Comment: I'd also add the `-c` option to grep, so it returns the line count, instead of using `wc`

Comment: i think egrep is depreciated.

Comment: The thing is that i have to maintain count in separate variables so that i can use these variables for comparison.

Commands are as follows.


isa_count=`grep ^ISA "${TMPFILE2}" | wc -l`
iea_count=`grep ^IEA "${TMPFILE2}" | wc -l`
st_count=`grep ^ST "${TMPFILE2}" | wc -l`
se_count=`grep ^SE "${TMPFILE2}" | wc -l`
gs_count=`grep ^GS "${TMPFILE2}" | wc -l`
ge_count=`grep ^GE "${TMPFILE2}" | wc -l`

I am looking for any command that can help me with above results and also faster than above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The command improved the time very well. But my files have different no of Counts i.e. say a big file only has 1 ISA while a small file has 1000 ISA. And this above method will consume more time in processing small files.. Is there any way to have a single command to store the different counts without creating new file?

Comment: I added `One More Option` you may like to try. No idea how it will perform.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
awk '/^ISA/ { ++isa_count }
     /^ST/ { ++st_count }
     /^GS/ { ++gs_count }
     /^IEA/ { ++iea_count }
     /^SE/ { ++se_count }
     /^GE/ { ++ge_count }
     END { print isa_count, st_count, gs_count,
           iea_count, se_count, ge_count }' really_big_file.dat
```

You could even store the `awk` program code (the stuff between the single quotes) in a separate file and then do something like:

```
awk -f count_patterns.awk really_big_file.dat
```

That just dumps the counts on your standard output, though. To get them into variables in your shell script, you would do something like this:

```
read isa_count st_count gs_count iea_count se_count ge_count < <(awk .....)
```

The advantage to this approach is that it scans the file only once to produce all the counts.

Edit: updated to use the actual example patterns from your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried running your command as               time awk '/^SE/ { ++counter1 } /^GE/ { ++counter2 } END { print counter1, counter2 }' 10047_RP_2014070218075858_00001_5010.txt .  this is taking 21 seconds while individual greps for two patterns are taking 10.40 seconds each.  Seems like no significant inprovement with respect to time.  i am searching for a option performance wise.

Comment: Can you specify in detail how to store individual values in variables?

Comment: Just replace the `.....` with the rest of the command line from the earlier examples - either the one spelling out the program explicitly, or the one where you've put the program in a file.